# Border on top bar div breaks at high zoom ( in ) < 20 lines of code | Easy

Tags: html, css

I'm working in firefox...not sure if it is browser dependent.

Olof just verfied in Chrome as well.

I'm trying to get my CSS displaying pixel perfectly.  I zoom in too look at it.  I'm having a problem such that the border I have on a top bar disappears at high zoom.  Not too sure why this is happening or what I can do to fix it.

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/DsNr2/

Here is the screenshot from the fiddle

[image]

Note you have to zoom in to see the border disappear.

I would expect to see the border from one side of the screen to the next but is stops in between...when you zoom in.

I'm not so much concerned with a user needing to zoom in (Control + on Firefox) but more for my own development needs and verifying everything is in place.

The top bar elements have been removed in the fiddle to narrow down to the causing agent.

Here is code from fiddle

```
<!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
MODULE - NORMALIZE/ALL
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

<style>
body{
  padding:  0px;
  margin:  0px;
  background:  #bfddec;
  line-height: 100%;
}

#A{
  background:  -moz-linear-gradient(top, #009fd0, #008db8);
  background:  -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #009fd0, #008db8);
  border-bottom:  1px solid #007fa5;
}
#Aa{
  position:  relative;
  width:  1000px;
  height:  40px;
  margin-left:  auto;
  margin-right:  auto;
  background:  -moz-linear-gradient(top, #009fd0, #008db8);
  background:  -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #009fd0, #008db8);
}

</style>

<!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
MODULE - HEADER
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

<div id='A'>
  <div id='Aa'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No problems for me. Using Google chrome.

Comment: Did you zoom in and scroll left and right?

Comment: Only thing I see is, as the left, ~1px difference in hight. Normal looking everything.

Comment: That's what I'm talking about 1px off...you verified in Chrome as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div `#A` has a 1px border at the bottom; the div `#Aa` does not.  `#Aa` is being rendered as wider than `#A`, so the 1px border at the bottom of `#A` stops.

Since `#Aa` spans the entire top of the screen, you can just apply the border to `#Aa` instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/DsNr2/9/

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  As it is, the border is only going as far as the width of the screen.

Comment: I need a 1px border that is uniform across the entire top border...setting it to A or Aa or both does not work...though setting it to A should work...seems like a browser bug.

Comment: Why would Aa ever be rendered as wider then A...Aa is inside of A in the html and has auto-margins

Comment: If it's a bug, it's certainly consistent across multiple browsers.  The following is how width is calculated for block style elements: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#blockwidth

/ I suspect that what's actually happening is that `#A` is taking on the effective width of 100%, which (at least on most monitors) in jsFiddle is less than 1000px, so it overflows.

Comment: what do you mean overflows..the programming kind or the CSS kind?

Comment: Just verified that adding in 100% to the width of A does not help

Comment: The CSS kind.  And I'm suggesting that the problem is that `#A` is already taking the width of 100%, rather than the width of its contents.

Comment: O.K...how does the effective width get to be less then 1000px...can you put it in laymen's terms.

Comment: I'm not entirely certain, but I think it might be because the width of the viewport is less than 1000px.  Regardless, I think your best bet is to try applying `min-width: 1000px` to `#A`.

Answer (score 1):

The margin-left: auto
and margin-right: auto
(which could be condensed down to margin: 0 auto;)

Seem to imply that you want the inner div to be centered.  This can't happen without a width on the parent div.

Maybe this is what you want?

```
#A{
  width: 100%;
}
#Aa{
  position:  relative;
  width:  1000px;
  height:  40px;
  margin-left:  auto;
  margin-right:  auto;
  background:  -moz-linear-gradient(top, #009fd0, #008db8);
  background:  -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #009fd0, #008db8);
  border-bottom:  1px solid #007fa5;
}
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking of doing....giving it a width....let me try that in the fiddle.

Comment: I tried that i had no effect..more proof that this is a bug..it does not actually take up 100% of the screen like it should.

Comment: In CSS, "100%" means 100% of the viewport, not the page.

Comment: What is a view port? is it the window object that JavaScript uses?

Comment: A [viewport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewport) is the visible portion of the screen.  It's a generic term that's not specific to JS or CSS.

Comment: If the view port is the viewable area then this makes a little more sense...I just would have guessed that the outer div would always have a greater width then the inner div...but I guess precedence goes to the "viewport"